# How build Node JS application using Docker for different staging environments

Tags: node.js, docker

this should have been routine, but I haven't been able to find any way. I am using Node with Docker for packaging. I have three environments: dev, qa, and prod, as usual. I have three configuration files with numerous variables: dev-config.json, qa-config.json, prod-config.json. I need Docker to pick up files and package them as **config.json** inside the Docker image. How to go about pl.. Thx

Answer (score 0):

For building an image with only the correct config file included, you can use [--build-arg](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg).

Add

```
ARG CONFIG_FILE
...
COPY $CONFIG_FILE config.json
```

in your docker file and then use

```
docker build --build-arg CONFIG_FILE=prod-config.json .
```

to build your image

**EDIT**

The other possibility is to put all your config files in your image and decide which one to use, when you startup the container. For instance, you could read the desired name of your config file from an environment variable (at runtime of the container, not to confuse with `ARG` and `--build-arg` at build-time of the image) which can be set when you start your container

Iw somewhere in your node app

```js
// read the config file name from the environment variable 
// and have a fallback if the environment variable is not defined
const configfilename = process.env.CONFIG_FILE || "config.json";
```

and when you start your container you can do

```
docker run --env CONFIG_FILE=prod-config.json  YOURIMAGE
```

to set the environment variable. This way, you will have only one image.

A third possibility would be to not add your configs in the container at all, but load them from external volume that you mount when you run the container. If you have different volumes for diffent configs, you can again decide at startup, which volume to mount. As you can give your config file the same name on every volume, your app does not need to be aware of any environment variables, you just have to make sure, you use the correct path to your config file and all volumes have the same file structure.

Ie in your node app

```js
const configfile = '/config/config.json';
```

and then you start your container mounting the correct config directory

```
docker run -v  /host/path/to/prod-config:/config YOURIMAGE
```

Comment: This gives you a different image per environment, so you'll be running an untested image in production.  That's not usually a best practice.

Comment: @DavidMaze Typically, you'd also test a production image in a staging environment before releasing it to production ...

Comment: Looks workable with the exception that we wll have one image per environment. I hope ths is standard practice.

Comment: @ApurvaSingh Please see the updated answer